# I could not make this work. ExtraButton To link to my Action (Srtus2-Jquery-Grid)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I am already stock.. I had created an extra button for struts2 jQuery Grid.. When I click the button, It should go to my Action. How to do this on click? Here is parts of my code.

```
 navigatorExtraButtons="{
            seperator: { 
            title : 'seperator'  
            }, 
            hide : { 
            title : 'Show/Hide', 
            icon: 'ui-icon-wrench', 
            onclick: function(){ load('<s:url action="ProductInitialise"/>')  } //--> this doesn't work.
            },
            alert : { 
            title : 'Alert', 
            caption : 'Show Alert!', 
            onclick: function(){ alert('Grid Button clicked!') }
            }
            }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navigatorExtraButtons` is a parameter of the `<sjg:grid />` Struts2(-jQuery Plugin) tag.

You can't put a Struts2 tag inside another Struts2 tag;

to do that, you must use `OGNL`, and in the case of `URL`s you should define the `URL`s outside the grid tag, and refer to them with `OGNL`, like that:

```
<s:url id="myUrl" action="ProductInitialise" namespace="/myNamespace"/>
```

....

```
onclick: function(){ load('%{myUrl}') }
```

Assuming all the rest is working (the `load` function for example), this should be enough to make it works.

Comment: Hi @Andrea Ligios Thank you very much. the function load did not work... however I had found another function." window.location = '%{myUrl}' ".  This is now okay. :) Thank you for the help.